# Why WCF when we have SignalR?

Tags: wcf, signalr

As we know WCF is a web service and SignalR is a technology for using it for bi-directional actions, So I would like to know what is the exact difference between WCF & SignalR and why can't we use SignalR in place of WCF??

Comment: WCF is no service. It is a part of .NET that allows you to create web services and configure those web services to your needs.

Comment: Yup am aware of it, Sorry missed the word web beside service

Answer (score 0):

SignalR is only used when the scenario is about real time bidirectional communication , the same can be achieved by using WCF with the appropriate binding
Though WCF is more suitable for request/response scenarios with more control over protocols used , security , encoding...etc
so SignalR is a better choice for real time communication and WCF is a much better choice for any other scenario